# AlertDialog background Transparent binding

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Если использую всё работает `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_purchase_premium)`
Если использую не работает `setContentView(binding.root)` layout перестаёт реагировать на указанные атрибуты margin
Вопрос как изменить `AlertDialog` `background` работая с `binding` и чтобы `layout` атрибуты margin реагировали на устанновленые значения

```
class PremiumPurchaseDialog(context: Context) : AlertDialog(context) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = FragmentPurchasePremiumBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        //не помогает
        window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        //не помогает
        window?.decorView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    }
}
```

Пробовал использовать AlertDialog(context, R.style.CustomDialog) не помогает

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
  <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может вам использовать DialogFragment? Когда я использую его, прозрачный фон и отступы работают. Ну и несомненный плюс DialogFragment - при смене ориентации он не убивается.